# Allowing variable in material UI RaisedButton Label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm playing arround with React and Material and I'm wandering how I can pass a variable in a Material UI component label ?

Here is my code :

```
const LoginForm = ({
    myVariable
}) => (
    {/*....*/}
    <RaisedButton type="submit" label={myVariable} primary/>
    {/*....*/}
);

LoginForm.propTypes = {
    myVariable : PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default LoginForm;
```

But, even if the label is displayed correctly in the browser (chromium), the console show me this warning :

```
warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop label or children or icon was not specified in RaisedButton.
```

**Edit:**
After some debugging, it occurs that the view is rendered several times (at least 4 times ???) and that in the 1st render, myVariable is undefined.

So, now, I have to manage why the component is rendered sevral times and why in the 1st render, variables are undefined.

So here my code.

**Base.jsx**

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Link, IndexLink} from 'react-router';

const Base = ({
  children
}) => (
  <div>
    <div className="top-bar">
    {children}
  </div>
);

Base.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Base;
```

**Auth.js**

```
class Auth {

  /**
   * Authenticate a user. Save a token string in Local Storage
   *
   * @param {string} token
   */
  static authenticateUser(token) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  }

  /**
   * Check if a user is authenticated - check if a token is saved in Local Storage
   *
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  static isUserAuthenticated() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token') !== null;
  }

  /**
   * Deauthenticate a user. Remove a token from Local Storage.
   *
   */
  static deauthenticateUser() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  /**
   * Get a token value.
   *
   * @returns {string}
   */

  static getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }
}

export default Auth;
```

**loginForm.jsx**

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import {Card, CardText} from 'material-ui/Card';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

const LoginForm = ({
  locales,
  onSubmit,
  onChange,
  errors,
  successMessage,
  user
}) => (
  <Card className="container">
    <form action="/" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <h2 className="card-heading">{locales.connect_to_your_account}</h2>

      {successMessage && <p className="success-message">{successMessage}</p>}
      {errors.summary && <p className="error-message">{errors.summary}</p>}

      <div className="field-line">
        <TextField
          floatingLabelText={locales.email}
          name="email"
          errorText={errors.email}
          onChange={onChange}
          value={user.email}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="field-line">
        <TextField
          floatingLabelText={locales.password}
          type="password"
          name="password"
          onChange={onChange}
          errorText={errors.password}
          value={user.password}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="button-line">
        <RaisedButton type="submit" label={locales.log_in} primary/>
      </div>

      <CardText>{locales.dont_have_account_yet} <Link to={'/request-account'}>{locales.request_one}</Link>.</CardText>
    </form>
  </Card>
);

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  locales       : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onSubmit      : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onChange      : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  errors        : PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  successMessage: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  user          : PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default LoginForm;
```

loginPage.jsx

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Auth from '../modules/Auth';
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm.jsx';

class LoginPage extends React.Component {

  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    const storedMessage = localStorage.getItem('successMessage');
    let successMessage  = '';

    if (storedMessage) {
      successMessage = storedMessage;
      localStorage.removeItem('successMessage');
    }

    // set the initial component state
    this.state = {
      locales: {},
      errors : {},
      successMessage,
      user   : {
        email   : '',
        password: '',
      },
    };

    this.processForm = this.processForm.bind(this);
    this.changeUser  = this.changeUser.bind(this);
  }

  // Load translations via an Api Rest
  componentDidMount() {
    const data = {
      connect_to_your_account: {},
      log_in                 : {},
      email                  : {},
      password               : {},
      dont_have_account_yet  : {},
      request_one            : {},
    };
    const xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('post', '/app_test.php/api/fr/translations');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');

    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        this.setState({
          locales: xhr.response,
        });
      }
    });
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  /**
   * Process the form.
   *
   * @param {object} event - the JavaScript event object
   */
  processForm(event) {
    // prevent default action. in this case, action is the form submission event
    event.preventDefault();

    // create a base64 encoded string
    const credentials = window.btoa(`${this.state.user.email}:${this.state.user.password}`);

    // create an AJAX request
    const xhr           = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.open('post', '/app_test.php/api/fr/tokens');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', `Basic ${credentials}`);

    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
      if (xhr.status === 201) {
        // success

        // change the component-container state
        this.setState({
          errors: {}
        });

        // save the token
        Auth.authenticateUser(xhr.response.token);

        // change the current URL to /
        this.context.router.replace('/');
      } else {
        // failure

        // change the component state
        const errors   = xhr.response.errors ? xhr.response.errors : {};
        errors.summary = xhr.response.message;

        this.setState({
          errors
        });
      }
    });
    xhr.send(null);
  }

  /**
   * Change the user object.
   *
   * @param {object} event - the JavaScript event object
   */
  changeUser(event) {
    const field = event.target.name;
    const user  = this.state.user;
    user[field] = event.target.value;

    this.setState({
      user
    });
  }

  /**
   * Render the component.
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <LoginForm
        locales={this.state.locales}
        onSubmit={this.processForm}
        onChange={this.changeUser}
        errors={this.state.errors}
        successMessage={this.state.successMessage}
        user={this.state.user}
      />
    );
  }

}

LoginPage.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default LoginPage;
```

routes.js

```
import Basepage from './containers/BasePage.jsx';
import LoginPage from './containers/LoginPage.jsx';
import Auth from './modules/Auth';

const routes = {
  // base component (wrapper for the whole application).
  component  : Basepage,
  childRoutes: [

    {
      path        : '/',
      getComponent: (location, callback) => {
        if (Auth.isUserAuthenticated()) {
          callback(null, DashboardPage);
        } else {
          callback(null, LoginPage);
        }
      }
    },

    {
      path     : '/login',
      component: LoginPage
    },

    {
      path   : '/logout',
      onEnter: (nextState, replace) => {
        Auth.deauthenticateUser();

        // change the current URL to /
        replace('/');
      }
    }

  ]
};

export default routes;
```

index.js (acces point)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {browserHistory, Router} from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes.js';

import '../styles/main.scss';

// remove tap delay, essential for MaterialUI to work properly
injectTapEventPlugin();

ReactDom.render((
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}/>
  </MuiThemeProvider>), document.getElementById('app')
);
```

The variables I try to send to the views are translated text retrieved via an Api Rest (translations is managed by the backend)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you code isn´t valid.. as far as i know it should be `primary={true}` . What is the content of `myVariable` ?

Comment: corrected the code to set primary={true} and it doesn't change anything. myVariable is just some random string.

Comment: As far as I know `prop={true}` and just `prop` are equivalent and both valid.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workarround, don't know if its a best practice or not :

```
label={`${myVariable}`}
```

Comment: it´s not. If you just do `label="myLabel"` the error is gone or?

Comment: Yes, if I use `label="myLabel"`, the error is gone, but I don't want to set a text directlly, I want a variable text. How I can do it using React best pratices ? Thanks.

Comment: I thought this, because all you do in yours answer is to fulfill the propType Requirement of a string. Can it be that `myVariable` is `undefined` on the first `render` ? You should really add your complete code!

Comment: I think you're totally right. I'll take some time to update my post with a complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [defaultProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values), `myVariable` might be `undefined` on the first render

```
LoginForm.defaultProps= {
    myVariable: "",
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is like el solo lobo said. But now I want to know why there is many render (at least 4 on the login page). I added the complete code in the original question. Thanks again.